# How to print row childs in datatables with a custom button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I already create row childs in datatables through an ajax call :

```
$('#tlistaseguimientos tbody').on( 'click', 'tr td.details-control', function () {
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = dt.row( tr );
            var idx = $.inArray( tr.attr('id'), detailRows );

            if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
                tr.removeClass( 'details' );
                row.child.hide();

                // Remove from the 'open' array
                detailRows.splice( idx, 1 );
            }
            else {

                tr.addClass( 'details' );
                str_return = format(row.data(),str_return);
                row.child( str_return ).show();
                str_return = "";
                // Add to the 'open' array
                if ( idx === -1 ) {
                    detailRows.push( tr.attr('id') );
                }
            }
            function format(d,str){
               var dato = "act=segna_segfalla&ent=general&id=" + d.idReporteFallaDetalle ;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./modelo/mngr_postventa.php",
                    data: dato,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                }).done(function(res) {
                    $.each(res, function(id,valor) {
                        //str = str + "Comentarios del Cliente: "+valor['dsComentarios'] +"<br>"+"ID : "+valor['idSeguimiento']+"<br>";
                        str = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>Estatus:</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+valor['estatus']+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>Motivo:</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+valor['motivo']+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>Fecha Visita:</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+valor['fecha']+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>Hora Visita:</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+valor['hora']+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                    '<td>Comentarios:</td>'+
                                    '<td>'+valor['comen']+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>'+
                            '</table>'
                    });

                }); 
                alert('Consultar el seguimiento '+d.idReporteFallaDetalle );
                return str;
            }
        } );´
```

But when I want to print it with the buttons API `'print'`, it´s only export the original data of the table, discarding the row childs.

I'm thinking create a custom button pushing to the original json data the row childs.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

I create the table with only the elements i want to show no matter the dimension of the div of the table, and I add the class `responsive` to the table tag `<table id="datatables" class="display compact table responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>` Following the example in [Class Responsive](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/initialisation/className.html)